# When was the last Chicago built Schwinn

Tags: vintage

I have a 1983 Schwinn Sierra, one piece crank, badge # 2733. Frame seams appear Chicago. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you can't find the answer anywhere else, it may lie in one of these linked articles.  (I don't remember where I got these, but they may have come from another question here, in which case all credit to whoever first posted them.) http://www.chicagobusiness.com/article/19931009/ISSUE01/100018007/the-fall-of-schwinn-pt-1-of-2 http://www.chicagobusiness.com/article/19931009/ISSUE01/100018008/the-fall-of-schwinn-pt-2-of-2 http://community.terrybicycles.com/media/podcastgen1.3/?p=episode&name=2010-11-16_schwinn.mp3

Answer (score 1):

That may very well be Chicago.  Here is a guide to the different badges they used:

http://re-cycle.com/History/Schwinn/SwnC_Badges.aspx

As I remember, the biggest giveaway was if the badge was affixed with machine screws, it was from Chicago.  If it uses rivets, it's overseas.

Oh, and 1982 was the last Chicago Schwinn.  So if that one is 1983, you missed it by a year.